# Check if Input fields and select fields are not set

Tags: jquery

So I am iterating through input fields and select options to see if they are set or not. If they are not set, then add a class. But the issue is that the select option will not work. Here is the code:

```
 var isValid;
 $("input, select option").not("#poster-img").each(function() {
 var element = $(this);
  if (element.val() == "" || element.attr('data-id') == "not-set") {
    isValid = false;
  $(this).addClass('is-invalid');
 }
 });
```

The `<select>` tag is not working. I want to be able to add a class to the select tags as well. Is it wise to use both input fields and select tags in one query or should I separate them both? I asked this because My class for Input fields `is-invalid` will not work for select input tags.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03hvdy97/19/)

As shown on the fiddle, if the `data-id` is set to `not-set`, then add the class to the select tag as well. Or in other sense, if nothing is selected (nothing being the first option with no value) then add the `is-invalid` class.

Comment: Your code looks OK. You say the "select option" will not work. Can you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem.

Comment: Also doesn't make sense validating  `<option>` and not it's parent `<select>`

Comment: As @charlietfl mentioned, there is now a JSFiddle linked with the OP

Comment: Missing `value=""` on the default `<option>` https://jsfiddle.net/03hvdy97/23/ When no `value` set on option the value of select becomes text  of option and therefore not empty

Comment: A simple test would be `console.log(element.val())`

Comment: How did I miss that! @charlietfl Thanks a bunch. So I will not be needing the `|| element.attr('data-id') == "not-set"` anyways lol.

Comment: Can you please update your answer so I can mark it as solved

Comment: well actually question doesn't show any of that and irregardless you were working with wrong element to start with and the missing value is a secondary problem

Comment: Sorry about that. Will keep in mind to have at least a working fiddle next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to validate `<option>` not `<select>` which is not normal

Try changing to:

```
$("input, select").not...
```

Or can use the shortcut selector [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

```
$(':input').not...
```

Comment: please check the jsfiddle linked with the question